# Define a `Task` setting with a `Task` in sbt 0.13.13

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to remove a deprecation warning on this setting when using sbt 0.13.13

```
task <<=
 (streams in Test, 
  loadedTestFrameworks in Test, 
  testLoader in Test,
  testGrouping in Test in test, 
  testExecution in Test in task,
  fullClasspath in Test in test, 
  javaHome in test) flatMap Defaults.allTestGroupsTask


 warning: `<<=` operator is deprecated. 
  Use `key := { x.value }` or `key ~= (old => { newValue })`.
  See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html
```

The `<<=` operator is now deprecated but I don't know how to rewrite the expression above.

I tried to rewrite it as:

```
task := Defaults.allTestGroupsTask(
  (streams in Test).value,
  (loadedTestFrameworks in Test).value,
  (testLoader in Test).value,
  (testGrouping in Test in test).value,
  (testExecution in Test in task).value,
  (fullClasspath in Test in test).value,
  (javaHome in test).value)
```

But I cannot assign a `Task[A]` to a `TaskKey` using `:=`

What should I do to remove `<<=` then?

Comment: `allTestGroupsTask` returns `Task[Output]`, so you either want to apply `.value` in the end or `.taskValue`

Comment: `.value` at the end raises `error: Illegal dynamic dependency` and I cannot find `.taskValue`, where is it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Def.taskDyn`:

```scala
task := Def.task {
  Def.task {
    Defaults.allTestGroupsTask(
      (streams in Test).value,
      (loadedTestFrameworks in Test).value,
      (testLoader in Test).value,
      (testGrouping in Test in test).value,
      (testExecution in Test in task).value,
      (fullClasspath in Test in test).value,
      (javaHome in test).value
    )
  }.value
}.value
```

Comment: I get 
` found: sbt.Tests.Output`
`required: sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[?]]
  task := Def.taskDyn(Defaults.allTestGroupsTask(`

Comment: And if I try one last `.value` I get `found   : sbt.Tests.Output`
 `required: sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[?]]
  task := Def.taskDyn(Defaults.allTestGroupsTask(`

Comment: Where is the key `task` defined? What type does it hold?

Comment: `task` is defined as `task: TaskKey[Tests.Output]`. My overall goal is to have a test task which I can run like `testOnly -- some options` from inside sbt.

Comment: Nesting two `Def.task` calls seems to do it [edit: updated answer to show this]. Note that one of your scopes is ` in Test in task`, instead of `in Test in test`. This might cause an error.

Comment: This is the final expression that finally worked for me: `  task := Def.taskDyn {
    Def.task(
      Defaults.allTestGroupsTask(
        (streams in Test).value,
        (loadedTestFrameworks in Test).value,
        (testLoader in Test).value,
        (testGrouping in Test in test).value,
        (testExecution in Test in task).value,
        (fullClasspath in Test in test).value,
        (javaHome in test).value
      )).flatMap(identity)
  }.value
`